# R: how to filter a timestamp by hour and minute?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I am struggling with the following example

```
time = c('2013-01-03 21:59:21.549', '2013-01-04 22:00:21.549', '2013-01-05 22:01:21.222', '2013-01-06 22:06:23.559' )
value = c(1,2,3,4)

data <- data_frame(time, value)
data <-data %>%  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time))

> data
# A tibble: 4 × 2
                 time value
               <dttm> <dbl>
1 2013-01-03 21:59:21     1
2 2013-01-04 22:00:21     2
3 2013-01-05 22:01:21     3
4 2013-01-06 22:06:23     4
```

How can I write a `dplyr::filter` statement than only keeps observations between `21:59` and `22:01` (included) every day?

Playing separately with `hour(time)` and `minute(time)` does not seem to work very well here.

Am I missing something here?

Output expected: row 1,2 and 3 only.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you substract the date (normalise everything to 1960-01-01 ? And then use a filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2019 is here! 
Here is a better (and simpler) solution using `as.hms`. The `tz` argument is mandatory.

```
    time_str = c('2013-01-03 21:59:21.549', '2013-01-04 22:00:21.549', '2013-01-05 
    22:01:21.222', '2013-01-06 22:06:23.559' )
    value = c(1,2,3,4)
    data <- tibble(time_str, value)

    data %>%  mutate(timestamp_utc = ymd_hms(time_str, tz = 'UTC'),
                     timestamp_est = with_tz(timestamp_utc, 'America/New_York'),
                            time_est = as.hms(timestamp_est, tz = 'America/New_York')) %>% 
      filter(time_est >= hms::as.hms('16:59:00', tz = 'America/New_York'),
             time_est <= hms::as.hms('17:01:00', tz = 'America/New_York'))
```

will do the job

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  time_str                value timestamp_utc           timestamp_est           time_est 
  <chr>                   <dbl> <dttm>                  <dttm>                  <time>   
1 2013-01-03 21:59:21.549     1 2013-01-03 21:59:21.549 2013-01-03 16:59:21.549 16:59.549
2 2013-01-04 22:00:21.549     2 2013-01-04 22:00:21.549 2013-01-04 17:00:21.549 17:00.549
```

Comment: This is great, after a lot of stumbling around I found your question and your answer and it works for the thing I need. Thank you.

Comment: thanks bro. you can upvote both question and answer if useful to you :)

Comment: as.hms() has been replaced by as_hms(), which is no longer generic and also does not have a tz argument. It also uses the time zone of the argument for conversion, not the current system's timezone. Change the timezone before converting if necessary, e.g. using lubridate::with_tz().

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned `hour` and `minute` from `lubridate` don't work but not sure I get why. Does this not work?

```
filter(data, 
    (hour(time) == 21 & minute(time) == 59) | 
    (hour(time) == 22 & minute(time) <= 1)
)
```

An alternative way is to get the number of seconds elapsed in the day and compare to the number of seconds corresponding to your desired limits.  The number of seconds elapsed in the day is calculated as the total number of seconds modulo the seconds in a day: `as.numeric(data$time) %% (60 * 60 * 24)`. The number of seconds elapsed until (the start of the minute) 21:59 is `60 * 60 * 21 + 60 * 59` and the number of seconds until (the end of the minute) 22:01 is `60 * 60 * 22 + 60 + 59`. Combining everything,

```
filter(data, between(as.numeric(time) %% (60 * 60 * 24),
                     60 * 60 * 21 + 60 * 59,
                     60 * 60 * 22 + 60 + 59
             )
 )
```

Comment: hey wait a minute! lemme think :)

Comment: ok yeah, what about filtering between `19:59` and `23:38` with your solution? :D

Comment: In that case you'd have to change the filtering condition to something like `(hour(time) == 19 & minute(time) == 59) | between(hour(time), 20, 22) | (hour(time) == 23 & minute(time) <= 38))`. I agree it gets a bit ugly. I'll post another method using seconds comparison

Answer (score 2):

Another idea would be the following. You can create a numeric vector using hour, minute, and second. You can extract them with `format()` and convert character to numeric. Then, you subset the data with the two numbers indicating the time range you want (i.e., 215900, 220100).

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(foo = as.numeric(format(time, "%H%M%S"))) %>%
filter(between(foo, 215900, 220100)) %>%
select(-foo)

#                 time value
#               <dttm> <dbl>
#1 2013-01-03 21:59:21     1
#2 2013-01-04 22:00:21     2
```

Comment: sounds a good idea as long as, for any time, the numeric representation mirrors the string representation. In other words, `04:34:23` should be `43423`?

Comment: @Noobie The first zero will be dropped when you convert character to numeric. So, that would not be an issue, I think. When your timestamps are in a.m. and p.m., my idea would not be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this solves your problem:

```
library(dplyr) 

result <- data %>%  
  mutate(time2 = format(time, format="%H:%M:%S")) %>%
  filter(time2 >= "21:59:00" & time2 < "22:02:00") %>%
  select(-time2)
```

Comment: nice! but my only worry is that `time2` is a character.Are we sure the comparison `time2 >= "21:59:00"` makes sense all the time (ah ah)

Comment: I had no problems filtering like this so far. Always got the result I wanted to have.

Comment: @Noobie See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833826/how-does-character-comparison-work-in-r/19834158#19834158) on character comparison.

Comment: thanks buddy. I am scared of the `This is a really dangerous approach` part though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of filtering time window can be attained by converting the timestamp to minutes or seconds (with time setup from 0000 - 2400), store it in a new variable and filter using the new variable.